# Get the Global Context in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way to `get the global context of Material App in Flutter`. Not the context of particular screen.

I am trying to get the context but it gives me the context of particular screen but I wan the context of MaterialApp.

Comment: For what purpose?  Context really only makes sense during a builder, like the build() method of a widget.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**If above solution does not works please try this solution.**

1. **Create the class**. Here it named as `NavigationService`

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class NavigationService { 
     static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = 
     GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
   }
   ```
2. **Set the navigatorKey property** of MaterialApp in the main.dart

   ```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey, // set property
     )
   }
   ```
3. Great! Now you can use anywhere you want e.g.

   ```
   print("---print context: 
     ${NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext}");
   ```

Comment: With null safety this doesn't work?

Comment: It works with null safety.

Answer (score 18):

**Assign a `GlobalKey()` to the `MaterialApp` which you can put in a separate class, let's call it `App` :**

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: App.materialKey, // GlobalKey()
      )
    }
```

Now wherever you want to get the `context` of the `MaterialApp`, you just have to call :

```
App.materialKey.currentContext
```

Here I'm printing `MaterialApp` `context` :

```
print('Material App Context : ${App.materialKey.currentContext}');
```

**OUTPUT :**
`flutter: Material App Context : MaterialApp-[GlobalKey#4fab4](state: _MaterialAppState#4bb44`)

Comment: Am new to flutter where do you get the App class as mine still doesnt have.

Comment: Is there a scenario where using a GlobalKey to get access to BuildContext is discouraged? To push a new route or show a SnackBar or a dialog, a BuildContext is required. To avoid passing BuildContext instances as arguments, I'd like to use the BuildContext of the GlobalKey. But I wonder if there's something I need to watch out for. One example of a bad use of global context I've thought of is dynamic InheritedWidget lookups.

Comment: @Geoff its a class you build on your own, see the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69299440/9528391

Answer (score 1):

If you use Getx State Management you can use;

```
GetMaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: Get.key,  
    );
```

Reach out with;

```
  BuildContext? context = Get.key.currentContext;
```

Comment: Getx is a library and It doesn't need a context construct. use it but I do not recommend it for professionals.

Comment: why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @EmilAdz here is a pretty good thread about why people usually don't recommend Getx:
https://twitter.com/scottstoll2017/status/1468431032240246784