# Undefined name 'context' in fuction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I defined a showSnackBarr() function in any separate dart file and used in other dart file but showing red line under this stared ** context.

`showSnackBar( **context** , e.toString);`

```
showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text(text),
  ));
}
```

```
on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){

      showSnackBar(context, e.message!);
      res = false;
}
```

Comment: can you add the widget from where you are calling `showSnackBar( context , e.toString);`?

Comment: No, Where should I add ?

Comment: you can updated the question with the code snippet

Comment: I edited my question plz help.

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable/instance member called `context` where you're invoking your function. Generally, `context` is available as a property in [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html) objects. An instance of `BuildContext` is also passed into the `build` method of Widgets.

More on [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html).

Comment: I did this that I intialize a variable into class add it is working final       ```BuildContext context ;
 AuthMethods({required this.context });```  Thank you so much Sir!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to show the snackbar from the function outside of the widget.

For that, you have to pass the BuildContext to the function along with any parameters.

Example:

```
void myFunc(BuildContext context, dynamic data){
    try{
        // perform operation
    }
    catch(e){
        showSnackBar(context, e.message!);
    }
}
```

and call the function from the widget  as

```
myFunc(context, "any data");
```

OR

you can use [global context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140195/4639894) if you do not want to pass the build context each time.

Comment: If I use this method then red line transfer myFuc(context, "any data");

Comment: you should call the  myFuc(context, "any data"); from your widget

Comment: I did this that I intialize a variable into class add it is working final       ```BuildContext context ;
 AuthMethods({required this.context });```

Answer (score 0):

I did this that I intialize a variable into the class where I using this function it is working final       `BuildContext context ; AuthMethods({required this.context });`

And make a constructor.