# Need to show dialog after async function but BuildContext has no widget

Tags: flutter

I have async function in a Flutter widget that will perform these steps:

```
Future<void> someFunction(BuildContext context) async {
  // step 1:
  // call async function that will result in removing current widget from the tree.
  await foo();

  // at this point the context has no widget since the widget is removed from the tree

  // step 2:
  // need to show a dialog which requires a context with a widget.
  // since the context has no widget, I am unable to show the dialog
  // What can we do here??

  showDialog(context: context, .....);
}
```

Can someone suggest a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try it with a global context? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139776/get-the-global-context-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That did work.  I don't have to worry about passing context to dialogs from now on.  Thanks

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using the global context that the article talks about?