# Global context is null

Tags: flutter

I'm using the global context as outlined in [Get the Global Context in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69299440/1040546) in a RetryPolicy which references an auth service when I get a 401:

```
class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  @override
  int get maxRetryAttempts => 1;

  @override
  bool shouldAttemptRetryOnException(Exception reason) {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      await Provider.of<UserProfileService>(NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!, listen: false).initLogin();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Randomly the `NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext` is null, is there anyway I can reinitialise this?