# How to show an Alert Dialog in an interceptor

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to fetch/post some information from/to the API. What I want is that any time I call an API and it returns an error (401, 403, 404, 500, etc...), I want an alert to popup and inform the user with the error details. I added the necessary interceptor to intercept the error and get the required information to show, however I could not find a way to show the alert.

```
class HttpCustomClient {
  static Dio configureDio() {
    final dio = Dio();
    dio.options.baseUrl = AppConsts.baseUrl;

    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onError: ((exception, handler) {
      var errorText = exception.response!.data['error'];

      //Insert code here to show an alert with errorText

      return handler.next(exception);
    })));

    return dio;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No interceptors are not for that purpose, you don't need them to show dialog or popup when you get **40x** or **500** response. You can sent different state for these response cases with **flutter_bloc** for example, and call *showAlertDialog* in **BlocListener** in UI code part. It is the best practise.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to call the Alert pop up on every single API call? What I am trying to do is that I write the code in the interceptor, this way I no longer need to worry about whether or not any API call fails, or if I create a new API I do not need to modify it in order to show an Alert if it fails

Comment: Yes there is. You can just call showAlertDialog on that interceptor inside (exception, handler) {}
Only problem you left is to call BuildContext globally from interceptor.

Comment: And you can do it using navigatorKey. You need context to use showAlertDialog. So you put ncontext from navigatorKey. Look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139776/get-the-global-context-in-flutter

Comment: Yes but showAlertDialog requires context to be passed, I even tried one_context but with no luck.

Comment: And if my comment helped you, then please upvote&accept it.

Comment: Probably we commented at same time. I wrote about how to get context. Please look for it.

Comment: It is working as expected now, thank you